# Join on same table - raw SQL to Laravel Query Builder or Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have the below raw sql query which works as expected

```sql
SELECT T1.category, T1.group, T1.series, T1.name, T2.cover
FROM (
    SELECT category, MAX(COALESCE(image)) as cover
    FROM stones
    GROUP BY `category`
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category) = 1
    ) T2
    INNER JOIN stones T1 on T2.category = T1.category;
```

While trying to convert it to Laravel Query Builder syntax, I tried the following

```php
DB::table('stones', 't1')
    ->select('t1.category', 't1.group', 't1.series', 't1.name', 't2.cover')
    ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT category, MAX(COALESCE(image)) as cover) FROM stones GROUP BY `category` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category)=1) t2'))
    ->join('stones as t2', 't2.category', '=', 't1.category')
    ->get();
```

It gives an error

```sh
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM stones GROUP BY `category` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category)=1) t2 inner join' at line 1 (SQL: select `t1`.`category`, `t1`.`group`, `t1`.`series`, `t1`.`name`, `t2`.`cover` from (SELECT category, MAX(COALESCE(image)) as cover) FROM stones GROUP BY `category` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category)=1) t2 inner join `stones` as `t2` on `t2`.`category` = `t1`.`category`)'
```

When I try to dump the sql generated by `toSql()`, I do not see any difference with the raw sql, however am unable to spot the mistake.

```sh
# dump from toSql()

"select `t1`.`category`, `t1`.`group`, `t1`.`series`, `t1`.`name`, `t2`.`cover` from (SELECT category, MAX(COALESCE(image)) as cover) FROM stones GROUP BY `category` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category)=1) t2 inner join `stones` as `t2` on `t2`.`category` = `t1`.`category`"
```

Comment: is the `)` in `as cover) FROM` necessary? cuz i didn't see that inside your first raw query but it's inside your DB query builder

Comment: i don't think you should use this query with eloquent just run it directly using `DB::statement("query");`

Comment: @Faesal Can you please elaborate on how to use `DB::statement('raw sql query here')` as it just returns a `bool` how do I get the statement to execute?

Comment: Does your raw sql query is successfully getting the result ?

Comment: Yes it is getting the desired result. And as pointed out by @ChanYungKeat & @adevel once I remove the extra `)` after `cover` and replace `stones as t2` with `stones as t1` in the `join()` - query builder statement also works - have posted the working query builder statement below for reference

Comment: sorry not statement i mean `select`

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with direct select like the following:

```php
$results = DB::select('SELECT T1.category, T1.group, T1.series, T1.name, T2.cover
FROM (
    SELECT category, MAX(COALESCE(image)) as cover
    FROM stones
    GROUP BY `category`
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category) = 1
    ) T2
    INNER JOIN stones T1 on T2.category = T1.category');
dd($results);
```

This will be much easier.

For more information check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database)

you can use the following `facade` methods instead of building eloquent query:

- `DB::select` for select complex query
- `DB::statement` for CRUD queries
- `DB::insert` for full insert queries directly
- `DB::update` for full update queries directly
- `DB::delete` for full delete queries directly

Note: all above methods should receive parameter bindings if needed

If you don't wanna bind parameters use `DB::unprepared('query')`

Comment: hope this can help @donkarnash

Comment: Yes you are spot on both the statements return identical results. For my use case I need to map over the result and convert the stdClass objects to array before applying the groupBy.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Have upvoted your answer as appreciation for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need another answer, but as a matter of personal taste I prefer avoiding `DB::raw()` whenever possible. With that in mind, I'd make use of the `fromSub()` method for the subquery:

```php
Stone::query()
    ->select('t1.category', 't1.group', 't1.series', 't1.name', 't2.cover')
    ->fromSub(function ($query) {
        $query->from('stones')
            ->select('category')
            ->selectRaw('MAX(COALESCE(image)) AS cover')
            ->groupBy('category')
            ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT category) = 1');
    }, 't2')
    ->join('stones AS t1', 't2.category', '=', 't1.category')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(['category', 'group', 'series'])
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: Wow thanks. I had completely forgotten about subqueries. I like this approach. Plus I don't carry the risk of SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that in Query builder the ")" after "cover" should no be there, if you compare the output query and the one that toSql spills taht is the diference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ChanYungKeat & @adevel for pointing out the correction "extra `)`". Removing that and swapping `stones as t2` with `stones as t1` in the `join()` makes it work. Below is the working query for reference

```php
DB::table('stones', 't1')
    ->select('t1.category', 't1.group', 't1.series', 't1.name', 't2.cover')
    ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT category, MAX(COALESCE(image)) as cover FROM stones GROUP BY `category` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category)=1) t2'))
    ->join('stones as t1', 't2.category', '=', 't1.category')
    ->get();
```

##### EDIT:

My use case need to group the query results by category > group > series and prepare the data for serialization  for consumption on front end. So I need an extra step to map over each result entry and convert it to an array (as stdClass objects returned from Query Builder may not serialize properly)

```php
DB::table('stones', 't1')
    ->select('t1.category', 't1.group', 't1.series', 't1.name', 't2.cover')
    ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT category, MAX(COALESCE(image)) as cover FROM stones GROUP BY `category` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category)=1) t2'))
    ->join('stones as t1', 't2.category', '=', 't1.category')
    ->get()

    /* Here I need to map over and convert the stdClass objects 
     * returned by Query  Builder to array for proper serialization
     */
    ->map(function ($stone) {
        return ['category' => $stone->category, 'group' => $stone->group, 'series' => $stone->series, 'name' => $stone->name, 'ccover' => $stone->cover];
    })

    ->groupBy(['category', 'group', 'series'])
    ->toArray();

//OR using DB::select() as suggested by @Faesal

return collect(DB::select("SELECT t1.category, t1.group, t1.series, t1.name, t2.cover FROM stones as t1 JOIN (SELECT category, MAX(COALESCE(image)) as cover FROM stones GROUP BY `category` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category)=1) t2 ON t2.category = t1.category"))

    /* Here I need to map over and convert the stdClass objects 
     * returned by Query  Builder to array for proper serialization
     */
    ->map(function ($stone) {
        return ['category' => $stone->category, 'group' => $stone->group, 'series' => $stone->series, 'name' => $stone->name, 'ccover' => $stone->cover];
    })
    ->groupBy(['category', 'group', 'series'])
    ->toArray();
```

I also found that it can be done using Eloquent (instead of Query Builder). Since Eloquent returns objects of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` there's not need for the extra step to map into array as serialization is taken care by the `Model` class.

```php
Stone::query()
    ->select('t1.category', 't1.group', 't1.series', 't1.name', 't2.cover')
    ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT category, MAX(COALESCE(image)) as cover FROM stones GROUP BY `category` HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category)=1) t2'))
    ->join('stones as t1', 't2.category', '=', 't1.category')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(['category', 'group', 'series'])
    ->toArray();
```

Hope this helps someone in a similar situation.